# How to upload a photo to Facebook in MVC3?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to upload a photo to a Facebook wall in MVC3 C#. I have tried several ways without results.

I'm not sure if this is achievable or not in MVC3. I have searched a lot on Google and Stackoverflow, but I didn't find a proper solution.

Could anyone help me? Please send your controller code and view page, with how to call this button to post images on Facebook wall.

I am stuck with my work, because of this upload photo to Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```
var attachment = new JsonObject();
var media = new[]{
    new{
        type="jpeg",
        src = filePath,
        title= "title", 
        artist= "art", 
        album= "album"
    }
};
//var mediaArray = new JsonArray { media };
attachment.Add("name", "sfs");
attachment.Add("href", "http://www.google.com");
attachment.Add("caption", " asdas");
attachment.Add("description", description);
attachment.Add("target_id", "1231231");
attachment.Add("media", media);

var sb = new StringBuilder("https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?");
sb.Append("message="); sb.Append(description + "&");
sb.Append("attachment=");
sb.Append(attachment);
sb.Append("&access_token=");
sb.Append(accessToken);
var req = WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: ok viral shah how can i call this in controller and in view page

Comment: can i use in my controller  [httppost] public ActionResult profile(){///}

Comment: @siva, you need to add facebook api on your code also which can be available from Facebook Developers Page..

Comment: i new to this environment that's y i asked you step by step process try understand my problem

Comment: i've app id and appsecret key of facebook then my doubt is how can call this in my view.cshtml page